# For loop not running inside of a function

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a character (char) jump in stages in a game using a for loop to jump a part of the way each time the loop run. The loop never initializes.

*Jump starting* is traced to the output console but the *jump No.* does not get traced.

Why is this?

> JumpHeight == 25

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
function loop(event:Event):void
{
    if (jumping == false && char.hitTestObject(floor) == false)
    {
        char.y += gravity
    }
}
function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == jumpKey)
    {
        jump()
    }
}

function jump()
{
    if (char.y >= groundY)
    {
        trace("Jump Starting")
        jumping = true
        for (jCycle = 0; jCycle == jumpHeight; jCycle++)
        {
            char.y -= gravity
            trace("Jump No. " + jCycle)
        }
        jumping = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that for condition is always false (jCycle == 0 !=jumpHeight) and body is unreachable.
Try this:

```
for (var jCycle:int = 0; jCycle <= jumpHeight; jCycle++)
{
     //body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the for loop condition: `jCycle == jumpHeight` should be `jCycle < jumpHeight` (or `jCycle <= jumpHeight`).